# Short exact sequence of Galois groups splits

Tags: galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory, exact-sequence

Let $K = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-D})$ be an imaginary quadratic number field for some $D >0$. Let $H$ be a finite Galois extension of $K$. There is the short exact sequence $$ \operatorname{Gal}(H/K)\to \operatorname{Gal}(H/\mathbb{Q})\to \operatorname{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q}) $$
Let $\tau\in\operatorname{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q})$ denote the only non-trivial element of complex conjugation. I want to say that the section $s: \operatorname{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q})\to \operatorname{Gal}(H/\mathbb{Q})$ by sending $\tau$ to $\tilde{\tau}$ which is also complex conjugation splits the short exact sequence. My reasoning is that this is because $\operatorname{Gal}(H/K)$ does not contain complex conjugation, since it has to fix $K$, which is not totally real.

Now, by assuming this, in what I'm investigating, I've come to a conclusion that doesn't really make sense. I want to check whether or not this assumption is the problem.

Comment: The map $Gal(H/\mathbb{Q}) \to Gal(K/\mathbb{Q})$ is just restriction from $H$ to $K$, right? So indeed, your map $s$ splits this map, because both $\tau$ and $\tilde{\tau}$ are the restrictions of complex conjugation.

Comment: Yes, it’s just the restriction. Does this still hold if I replace $K$ with any other Galois number field? I.e. any Galois group is a semi-direct product of its normal subgroups and quotients? I feel like it would no longer be true.

Comment: I don't think it is. In this case, you have a very special situation, which is that $Gal(K/\mathbb{Q})$ is cyclic, which makes it easy to define a morphism $Gal(K/\mathbb{Q}) \to Gal(H\mathbb{Q})$ - you just have to specify an element of order $|Gal(K/\mathbb{Q})|$. Moreover, it is possible to guarantee that this is a section because there is an element of $Gal(H/\mathbb{Q})$ of order two which restricts to the generator of $Gal(K/\mathbb{Q})$.

Comment: But in general, I don't see an obvious way to define a *group homomorphism* $Gal(K/\mathbb{Q}) \to Gal(H/\mathbb{Q})$. The point is that while the map $Gal(H/\mathbb{Q}) \to Gal(K/\mathbb{Q})$ given by restriction is surjective, meaning that every element of $Gal(K/\mathbb{Q})$ extends to an automorphism of $H/\mathbb{Q}$, these automorphisms of $H$ may not satisfy the same group theoretic relations that their restricted counterparts in $Gal(K/\mathbb{Q})$ do.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. So it holds at least when $K/\mathbb{Q}$ is cyclic. Thanks, that was very helpful.

Comment: No problem, glad to help! But it's not true in general when $K/\mathbb{Q}$ is cyclic, too. Again, you need the property that there is a lift of the unique generator of $Gal(K/\mathbb{Q})$ to $Gal(H/\mathbb{Q})$ which also has order $2$, which is special to your case. Consider the example where $H$ is a cyclic extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ of degree $4$, and let $K$ be the unique fixed quadratic subfield. Then your exact sequence is the usual non-split exact sequence $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$!

Comment: Are you assuming that $H$ is Galois also over $\Bbb{Q}$? Otherwise $H$ need not be stable under complex conjugation. For example $H=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{2+i})$ is Galois over $K=\Bbb{Q}(i)$, but $\sqrt{2-i}\notin H$.

Comment: Yes, you’re absolutely right. $H$ being Galois over $\mathbb{Q}$ is an assumption that I overlooked completely! It might be where all of my issues are actually coming from. Thanks for pointing it out.